# why is the definition of "over plus noun" not true?

Tags: grammar, superlatives

Yesterday, we learned about superlative and compression. My teacher of English that adjective like:
overprotected
overused
are not superlative? Why?

To complete my qeustion and clarified it I add more details to my question:
Also, another example: overqualified. Why also this word is also not superlative? and more example with the same style?

Answer (score 1):

Those are "over + adjective", not noun.

They are quite different from superlatives, in that they express a judgment.

The core meaning of a superlative is "more than any other":

> *That is the biggest bouquet I have ever seen.* = I have never seen a bigger one.

It is sometimes used colloquially for "very" with a sense of excitement:

> *They gave me the biggest bouquet!* = a very big one, and I am excited about it.

The prefix *Over-* means "very, in fact too much". So an overprotective parent is one that protects their children to a degree that causes problems (in the view of the speaker). A phrase that is overused is one that (in the opinion of the speaker) is used too much.